# Good browser plugin to display TIFFs

Tags: browser, plugins, tiff

I'm trying to develop a web version of an app we have that stores document images.  However, a good portion of the images are tiff's, which IE can't natively display.  Can anyone recommend a good plugin that will display them properly?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to have the web application convert the images to something standard either on the fly or using some caching mechanism and then allowing the user to download the tiff format if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the QuickTime plugin handles TIFF acceptably - however at the cost of having QuickTime around. Unfortunately this is not negligible - QuickTime has never been too friendly on Windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime should work, but keep in mind that TIFF files are usually not optimized for size, and are often much larger than JPEG resp. PNG renderings of the same image.

To avoid slow page loads, it might be better to convert the images to JPEG resp. PNG for display, as others suggested

Answer (score 1):

I found a good one at alternatiff.com, in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

quicktime will do it.